# How can we display section name AND its number in a simple way?

Tags: hyperref

How can we set display section name AND its number in a simple way in Latex?

e.g.

**Chapter 2** reviews .....

```
\chapter{Basics of continuum mechanics\label{ch:capitel2}}
```

Wish effects in the attachment JPG File.[image]

Comment: You should take a look at the `cleveref` package (to be loaded after `hyperref` if you load the latter), and more specifically the `\Cref` command.

Comment: @Bernard but word effects is not equal to the attached jpg file, namely,  Chapter 2 is active and not only number 2...

Comment: You didn't mention this requirement. Could you please post a minimal, yet compilable, code?